# Renaming the blob storage file

Tags: azure-blob-storage, dynamics-business-central

I have a problem with changing the name because as you can see in the code below I download the blob by name but this name is an identifier I would like the name to be changed to the name that is stored in the database and the blob to have the identifier

```
area(Processing)
    {
        action(Download)
        {

            ApplicationArea = All;
            Caption = 'Download';
            Image = Download;

            trigger OnAction();

            begin

                ABSBlobClient.GetBlobAsFile(Rec.BlobName);
            end;
        }
    }
```

whether it can be done at all and how because this getblobasfile method is systemic and I cannot modify it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Storage Blob Rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734672/azure-storage-blob-rename)

Comment: only it is in C# language and I need a version for dynamic business centers

Answer (score 0):

I used takeigo for this and it works

```
begin
    ABSBlobClient.GetBlobAsStream(Rec.BlobName, ToFile);
    file.DownloadFromStream(ToFile, '', '', '', Rec.Name);
end;
```